# How to handle divide by zero in GENERATED columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, generated-columns

I am using `GENERATED AS` columns in MySQL 5.7 as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE report_user 
MODIFY avg_trans_out_amount bigint 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round(trans_out_amount/(trans_out_count))) STORED;
```

but sometimes the `trans_out_count` could be 0, then the `GENERATED AS` column will give a divide by zero error. So, what I did was:

```
ALTER TABLE report_user 
MODIFY avg_trans_out_amount bigint 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round(trans_out_amount/(trans_out_count + 0.00001))) STORED;
```

but can be a little problematic - for example for `100,000/1.00001`, the right value is 100,000, but the actual value it not correct `9,999.90`. What should I do to handle this problem? This is the table DML:

```
CREATE TABLE `report_user` (
  `trans_into_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '转入次数',
  `trans_out_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '转出次数',
  `trans_into_amount` bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '转入金额',
  `trans_out_amount` bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '转出金额',
  `avg_trans_into_amount` bigint(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round((`trans_into_amount` / (`trans_into_count` + 0.00001)),0)) STORED,
  `avg_trans_out_amount` bigint(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round((`trans_out_amount` / (`trans_out_count` + 0.00001)),0)) STORED,
  `user_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '用户名',
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '用户ID'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36149 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin COMMENT='提转统计';
```

Comment: Can you provide table structure ?

Comment: I added the table dml @JYOTIRAJAI

Comment: average is undefined for count=0, so I would suggest NULLIF() as suggested by @jyoti-rajai in his answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to handle `DIVIDE BY ZERO` error in your case :

> **1) USING `IF()` :**

```
ALTER TABLE report_user 
modify avg_trans_out_amount bigint 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round(trans_out_amount/if(trans_out_count,0,1))) STORED;
```

> **2) USING `NULLIF()` :**

```
ALTER TABLE report_user 
modify avg_trans_out_amount bigint 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round(trans_out_amount/nullif(trans_out_count,1))) STORED;
```

> **3) USING `GREATEST()` :**

```
ALTER TABLE report_user 
MODIFY avg_trans_out_amount bigint 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round(trans_out_amount/greatest(trans_out_count,1))) STORED;
```

Answer (score 0):

aready tried out, I am using this sql to solve my problem:

```
ALTER TABLE report_user 
MODIFY avg_trans_out_amount bigint 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    round(trans_out_amount/(case when trans_out_count=0 then 1 else trans_out_count end))
) STORED;
```

Comment: This gives an incorrect answer - it should be `NULL` - the result of a division by 0 is not defined - IMHO?